# Gulpfile end of task with two different operations

Tags: gulp, translation

I am kind of lacking imagination on that one.
My goal is to retrieve a json object so I can run a replace string on all the files I want to translate, I have looked into a lot of translation libraries but this way is the best i can think of for my use.
Anyway my issue here is Once I got my json object, I have to run on all the files and when it is done, finish the task 'trad'.
I have done some research and tried a lot of things but there is something that I miss, something that I didn't understood about the good way to do that ?
Please help !

```
    gulp.task('trad', gulp.series( 'createTradFile', 'copyBeforeTrad',  function( done ) {
    var data = require('gulp-data');
    var path = require('path');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var replace2 = require('gulp-string-replace');
    var transObj = null;

    var translateAll = function()
    {
        var files = gulp.src(['fr/**/*.html', 'fr/**/*.js']);

        for (var k in transObj)
        {
            if (transObj[k].ID)
            {
             console.log("TRAD " + transObj[k].ID + " TO " + transObj[k].LANG1);

                files.pipe(replace2(new RegExp('\\+' + transObj[k].ID + '\\+', 'g'),
                                    transObj[k].LANG1,
                                    {'logs': {'enabled': true}}))
                .pipe(chmod(755));
            }
        }
        files.pipe(gulp.dest("fr"))
             .on('end', done);
    };

    gulp.src('distTemp/wording.json')
                .pipe(data(function(file) {
                    transObj = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync('distTemp/' + path.basename(file.path)));
                    console.log("TRAD first part OK");
                    translateAll();
                 })); 
   }));
```

So this code will translate like I want it too, but the task does not end :

```
[16:38:34] The following tasks did not complete: trad, <anonymous>
[16:38:34] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Comment: At a minimum put a return before that gulp.src.

Comment: Well thanks it works ! I don't know why I thought the done() call was enough without having to return the promise ... I still think I should write it differently but thanks for the save !

Comment: Ok so I should have been more specific : If you add the return it will then end the task at the end of the pipe(data) but not as intended at the end of the translateAll ( and more specifically at the end of the files.dest() )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a bit of research I found this ( almost crappy ) solution, which do the trick ( please answer if you hava a better solution )

```
var transObj = null;

gulp.task("retrieveTradObject", function(){
var data = require('gulp-data');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

return gulp.src('distTemp/wording.json')
            .pipe(data(function(file) {
                transObj = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync('distTemp/' + path.basename(file.path)));
                console.log("TRAD first part OK");
             }));
});

gulp.task('trad', gulp.series( 'createTradFile', 'copyBeforeTrad', 'retrieveTradObject',  function( done ) {

var replace2 = require('gulp-string-replace');

var files = gulp.src(['fr/**/*.html', 'fr/**/*.js']);

for (var k in transObj)
{
    if (transObj[k].ID)
    {
     console.log("TRAD " + transObj[k].ID + " TO " + transObj[k].LANG1);

        files = files.pipe(replace2(new RegExp('\\+' + transObj[k].ID + '\\+', 'g'),
                            transObj[k].LANG1,
                            {'logs': {'enabled': true}}))
        .pipe(chmod(755));
    }
}
files.pipe(gulp.dest("fr"));
return files;
}));
```

So main idea here was to separate the two promises into task ( mainly for a better understanding of the code for later ) and then to do the files = files.pipe( ... ) Which is explained here : [How to create repeating pipe in gulp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229633/how-to-create-repeating-pipe-in-gulp)

Hope this can help !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question 100% so I'll take the dv's, but are talking about something like [gulp-run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence)?

You can do all sorts of tasking stuff like this

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
//webp images for optimization on some browsers
const webp = require('gulp-webp');
//responsive images!
var responsive = require('gulp-responsive-images');
//gulp delete for cleaning
var del = require('del');
//run sequence to make sure each gulp command completes in the right order.
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
// =======================================================================// 
// !                Default and bulk tasks                                //        
// =======================================================================//  
//default runs when the user types 'gulp' into CLI
//first clean is ran, then webp, then the rest are ran async.
//If you want something ran after, you can add something like 'example'
gulp.task('default',function(callback){
    runSequence('clean','webp',['responsive-jpg','responsive-webp','copy-data','copy-sw'],'example'),callback
});
// =======================================================================// 
//                  Images and fonts                                      //        
// =======================================================================//  
gulp.task('responsive-jpg',function(){
    gulp.src('src/images/*')
    .pipe(responsive({
        '*.jpg':[
        {width:1600, suffix: '_large_1x', quality:40},
        {width:800, suffix: '_medium_1x', quality:70},
        {width:550, suffix: '_small_1x', quality:100}
    ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/images'));
});
gulp.task('responsive-webp',function(){
    gulp.src('src/images/*')
    .pipe(responsive({
        '*.webp':[
        {width:1600, suffix: '_large_1x', quality:40},
        {width:800, suffix: '_medium_1x', quality:70},
        {width:550, suffix: '_small_1x', quality:80}
    ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/images'));
});
gulp.task('webp', () =>
    gulp.src('src/images/*.jpg')
        .pipe(webp())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/images'))
);
gulp.task('copy-data', function () {
    gulp.src('./src/data/*.json')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/data'));
});
gulp.task('copy-sw', function () {
    gulp.src('./src/sw.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});
```

In my example here, I clear out old files, then I convert any images that need to be converted to webp, then I async the tasks that can be run together. You can do this in any arrangement you need. You could create then a gulp task that even points to two gulp run sequence tasks to double down on the effectiveness.

Comment: That s interesting but not really what i intended i use gulp.series to achieve what you say. My issue was to use a for inside a pipe and then be able to know when it ended.

Comment: Copy that so in my example I am showing how you can run tasks and complete them before having them piped to a final task, which seemed to be what you were doing? For instance, you'd run "trad" with run-sequence at the end of all of your json translations?